How to make Lagrangians Transversal by Hamiltonian Perturbations?
Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be two Lagrangians in a symplectic manifold $M$. In order to define $HF(L_1,L_2)$ (Lagrangian Floer homology of $L_1$ and $L_2$), we need the two Lagrangians to intersect transversely and if they don't intersect transversely, for a generic choice of a hamiltonian $H$ on $M$, we can assume $L_1$ meets $\Phi_H(L_2)$ transversely. My question is: how do we prove there is a generic set of hamiltonians that makes the intersection transversal? I guess we need to define a Fredholm map in terms of $L_1$ and $C^1(M\times I)$ and use Sard-Smale theorem, but I could'nt figure out the exact set up. Do you know any reference for this?

Let's consider the following equivalent statement: Given two Lagrangian submanifolds $L_1, L_2 \subset (M, \omega)$ (with $L_1$ compact), then for a generic choice of Hamiltonian $H : M \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ ('generic' in the $C^1$-sense), $\Phi^1_H(L_1)$ intersects $L_2$ transversally. In fact, we shall show that $H$ can be chosen within a dense open set of Hamiltonian functions. (Note: the following answer only goes over the main ideas of the proof; the technical details are left aside.)
Proof. As any $H$ is a $C^1$-small perturbation of some Hamiltonian $K$, then replacing $L_1$ by $\Phi_K(L_1)$, we may reduce to the case when $H$ is $C^1$-small (i.e. a $C^1$-small perturbation of the zero Hamiltonian).
By Weinstein's Lagrangian neighborhood theorem, there are (arbitrarily 'thin') tubular neighborhoods $L_1 \subset U \subset M$ and $L_1 \subset V \subset T^*L_1$ (where, in the latter case, $L_1$ is identified with the zero section of $T^*L_1$) such that $(U, \omega)$ and $(V, \omega_{\tiny{\mbox{canonical}}})$ are symplectomorphic. We may consider Hamiltonians $H$ that are so $C^1$-small that, when seen in the 'chart' $(V, \omega_{\tiny{\mbox{can}}})$, the Lagrangian $\Phi_H(L_1)$ is a section of the bundle $T^*L_1 \to L_1$. (Recall that Lagrangians in $(U, \omega)$ that are sufficiently $C^1$-close to $L_1$ correspond in $(V, \omega_{\tiny{\mbox{can}}})$ to sections of $T^*L_1$ (contained in $V$) that are graphs of (sufficiently small) closed $1$-form on $L_1$.)
Openness. Suppose $L_1 = \Phi_0(L_1)$ is transverse to $L_2$. Then for every sufficiently $C^1$-small $H$, the Lagrangian $\Phi_H(L_1)$ is still transverse to $L_2$. This is clearer when seen in the 'chart' $(V, \omega_{\tiny{\mbox{can}}})$: every (small) section of $T^*L_1 \to L_1$ is transverse to $L_2$, Lagrangian or not.
Density. We need to find arbitrarily small Hamiltonians $H_i$ such that $\Phi_{H_i}(L_1)$ are all transverse to $L_2$.
Since $L_1$ is compact, it can be covered by finitely many charts $(W_j)_{j=1, \dots, N}$. In each such chart $W_j$, we have $n := \mathrm{dim}(L_1)$ linearly independent coordinate functions $x_{jk}$ ($k=1, \dots, n$). Using (appropriate) bump functions, each $x_{jk} : W_j \to \mathbb{R}$ extends to a smooth function $H_{jk} : L_1 \to \mathbb{R}$. We consider the collection $\{H_{jk}\}_{j=1, \dots, N ; k = 1, \dots, n}$. By construction (if the charts $W_j$ and the bump functions have been suitably chosen), the collection of differentials $\{dH_{jk}\}_{j=1, \dots, N ; k = 1, \dots, n}$ spans $T^*_p L_1$ for every point $p \in L_1$.
If $\pi : T^*L_1 \to L_1$ denotes the canonical bundle map, then consider $\pi^* H_{jk} : V \to \mathbb{R}$; using a bump function supported in $V$ and using Weinstein's neighborhood symplectomorphism, these functions become defined on $M$. For simplicity, let's continue to denote all of these functions $H_{jk}$.
Consider the Hamiltonian flow $\Phi^t_{H_{jk}}$ generated by $H_{jk}$. Note that 'over' the chart $W_j \subset L_1 \subset U \subset M$, for small $t$, the flow $\Phi^t_{H_{jk}}$ moves $W_j$ in a transverse direction to $W_j$, namely, for $p \in W_j$, in the direction of the $1$-form $d H_{jk}|_{p} \in T^*_p L_1$ (assuming again that the previous bump functions have been suitably chosen).
We can now define a map $\Psi : L_1 \times [-1,1]^{Nn} \to M$ as
$$ \Psi(p, (t_{jk})_{j=1, \dots, N ; k = 1, \dots, n}) = \left(\prod_{j=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^n \Phi^{t_{jk}}_{H_{jk}} \right)(p) \, .$$
By construction, we see that along $L_1 \times \{0^{nN}\}$, the differential $T\Psi$ is surjective; this shows that for some small $\epsilon > 0$, the restriction $\Psi : L_1 \times [-\epsilon,\epsilon]^{Nn} \to M$ is a submersion onto its image, hence this map is transverse to $L_2$.
By the parametric transversality theorem, it follows that for almost every $(t_{jk})_{j=1, \dots, N ; k = 1, \dots, n} \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]^{Nn}$, the map $\Psi_{(t_{jk})_{j=1, \dots, N ; k = 1, \dots, n}} : L_1 \to M$ is transverse to $L_2$. But this is the restriction to $L_1$ of the Hamiltonian map $\Phi_{(t_{jk})_{j=1, \dots, N ; k = 1, \dots, n}} := \prod_{j=1}^N \prod_{k=1}^n \Phi^{t_{jk}}_{H_{jk}} : M \to \mathbb{R}$. QED
Remark. It seems to me difficult to proceed along the 'Sard-Smale approach' that you suggested, for this would require to 'turn' the set of Hamiltonian functions 'into' a Banach manifold, which is a nontrivial task considering that the spaces of $C^k$-functions are not Banach spaces (as they are incomplete). If one were to 'remove' Hamiltonians to make a Banach manifold, then one would achieve genericity only within a subset of Hamiltonians; if one were to 'add' 'Hamiltonians' to make a Banach manifold, then it is unclear how these 'Hamiltonians' would act on $M$ and genericity might perhaps be achieve only among these 'additional Hamiltonians'...
